# How do I get the pickers Geopoint in flutter_osm_plugin, when isPicker = true?

Tags: flutter, openstreetmap, picker

I work on an app, and I have a OSMFlutter map that works fine.

Here is some of the code:

```
          SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: OSMFlutter(
              controller: mapController,
              trackMyPosition: true,
              isPicker: true,
```

and then other options.

My Question is how to get the GeoPoint details from the picker?
I've attached a screenshot of the map. The map is perfect, but how do I get latitude and longitude?[Screenshot from my smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4r6T.jpg)

I have trackMyPosition set to true, but that doesn't track the changes that happens when I move the map, to pick a new position.

I can't see where to get the position under the picker. Help please...

Comment: My assumption was that it would be easier and more logical to use the isPicker = true, and then read the position of the picker. Since I've had no answers yet, I proceeded to use the showSimplePickerLocation dialog. It works, but I'm still interested in answers to the isPicker mystery.